# Zuul Gateway Server is not showing any routes

Tags: java, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am have created an Gateway Server and registered it with Eureka. Below it is the bootstrap class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayServerApplication {
   ...
}
```

I have integrated Zuul Gateway Server with Eureka Server. Everything is going OK. Eureka is starting successfully and the also the Gateway Server is starting successfully.
Nevertheless, I am having trouble accessing the routes. Below is the link that i am trying to access:

`https://localhost:5555/actuator/routes`

Please, help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

P.S my configuration information for gateway server in application.properties file:

```
#Application
server.port=5555

#Eureka
cloud.config.enabled=true
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka-server/


#Actuator
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.security.enabled=false
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration? application.properties for both projects.

Comment: I added the configuration information above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `@EnableZuulServer` to `@EnableZuulProxy`, like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayServerApplication {
   ...
}
```

You have two option for creating  `Zuul Gateway Server`:

- The first one is to use `@EnableZuulServer` annotation. This annotation creates a Zuul Server but doesn't offer the Zuul pre-built routing capabilities. You use this annotation when you want to build your own routing service.
- The second option is to use the `@EnableZuulProxy` annotation. This annotation creates Zuul Server, loads the Zuul Reverse Proxy Filters, and automatically uses Eureka Server to lookup services by their service IDs and then use Netflix Ribbon to do client-side load balancing of requests from within Zuul.

I think in your case is more suited to use `@EnableZuulProxy` annotation because you don't want to build your own custom service.